# WCF object graph not returned

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created a WCF service that returns a complex object graph, there are quite a few objects in the graph but it isn't excessive (less than 30).

When testing against my local system the service works fine, this is IIS7. We then uploaded the service to our test server which is IIS 6 and the service no longer works.

Checking the server logs we can see that our service method executes correctly and returns the correct object graph. However WCF doesn't transmit this result back to the calling client.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

It seems that one of the enumerations on the main object is causing the whole response not to be returned. This enumeration is of an object with 3 string properties and 1 guid. Other enumerations are returned ok, I am not sure why this one. This is the definition:

```
[DataContract]
public class OtherFields    {

    [DataMember]
    public string Caption
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]        
    public string Help { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is some exception thrown on the client?

Comment: Some binding, transport you are using, aspNetCompatibility, ... will be useful. Also explaining what you mean by graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problems was that the parent object used a generic enumerable to hold the list of OtherFields objects. Changing this to an array has resolved the problem

Comment: Good that the problem was resolved. I wish we knew why it worked on your environment but not in deployment.

Comment: I am not sure what the difference in the environments was, I have .Net 4.0 on my dev system but only 3.5 on the server. I wonder if this made a difference.